# Switch statement to return class instance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

In my UITableView I am passing an array of data and each data has a unique ID. I want to call a certain function within that class by initializing the class via the unique id

I could do the statement within the cell but It is useful to make it a reusable function later on (which I plan to)

```
class GetFoodModel {

    var modelArr : NSMutableArray = []

    func modelByKey(key : String) -> Any {
        switch key {
            case "breakfast":
                return BreakfastData() as BreakfastData
            case "lunch":
                return LunchData() as LunchData

        default:
           return false
        }

    }


}
```

Basically here is how I want to call it:

(Not exactly my code just an example of how I'd like it)

```
let FoodClass = GetFoodClass()
let TheClass = FoodClass.modelByKey(key: uniqueID)
let totalFoods = TheClass.totalFood()
```

I have tired to use `AnyClass` although the properties don't show up for that class.

The function name is universal for each of these classes. When you initialize the class the array within gets populated. I then call this function to return the count.

```
class BreakfastData {

    myArr : NSArray = []

    init() {
       myArr.append('Eggs')
       myArr.append('Ham')
    }

    func totalFood() -> Int {

    return myArr.count

    }

}
```

Comment: How is your `totalFood()` method defined? Is it a sort of class method common to `BreakfastData` and `LunchData`? Or some other thing?

Comment: @OOPer yes it's a universal function name that these classes will have. I just have it doing an array count within the class and returning an Int

Comment: It is very important if `totalFood()` is a class method or an instance method. Please show by example.

Comment: dont type cast within modelBykey try to type case here FoodClass.modelByKey(key: uniqueID) and then see what the type of your class

Comment: @OOPer Updated, it would be a class method

Comment: @ShauketSheikh It does not return a type, If I return the function 'AnyClass' it wont cast it to my class.

Comment: Your method does not have `static` or `class` is it really a class method?

Comment: it is instance method

Comment: can i see GetFoodClass implementation ?

Comment: @ShauketSheikh Updated again

Comment: It's an instance method...

Comment: @Victori i have created sample project, its working in my side can i see your GetFoodClass implementation how he returning GetFoodModel object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you just need a protocol representing that the class conforming to the protocol has the method `totalFood()`.

```
protocol FoodDataType {
    func totalFood() -> Int
}

class BreakfastData: FoodDataType {
    var myArr: [String] = []

    init() {
        myArr.append("Eggs")
        myArr.append("Ham")
    }

    func totalFood() -> Int {
        return myArr.count
    }
}

class LunchData: FoodDataType {
    var myArr: [String] = []

    init() {
        //populate myArr
        //...
    }

    func totalFood() -> Int {
        return myArr.count
    }
}

class GetFoodModel {

    func modelByKey(key : String) -> FoodDataType? {
        switch key {
        case "breakfast":
            return BreakfastData()
        case "lunch":
            return LunchData()

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let uniqueID = "breakfast"

let foodModel = GetFoodModel()
if let theFoodData = foodModel.modelByKey(key: uniqueID) {
    let totalFoods = theFoodData.totalFood()
    print(totalFoods)
}
```

Comment: yeah that the correct way. i also typing the answer :D

Comment: @ShauketSheikh, in fact, I had prepared two versions of code, one is instance method version, and the other is static method version... And this is the one adapted to the latest update... Quite a work...

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend against initializing to an empty array, only to then append multiple items in the `init()`. Just initialize it direct to the literal `var myArr =  ["ham", "eggs"]`. Also, note to OP, please use your knowledge of the problem domain to come up with a better name to replace `myArr`